# Why javascript value property doesn't work like manually change?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ninja-forms

I have some problem with triggering action. I have range slider and input type number.

Input number is hidden and my range input is changing value of input number like this:

```js
function updateTextInput_water(val) {
  var input = document.getElementById('nf-field-32');
  document.getElementById('nf-field-32').value = val;
  input.value;
  input.setAttribute('value', input.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="range" value="20" name="rangeInput" min="1" max="101" onchange="updateTextInput_water(this.value);">
<input type="number" id="nf-field-32" name="nf-field-32 value=" 20 " min="1 " max="101 " step="1 ">
```

I have some action when input number is set to specific number. It works when i manually change number with keydown and keyup, also it works when i type from the keyboard this specific number, but it doesnt work when i use slider to change value of my input number.

Why?

Trigger action (show/hide):

```
/**
 * Handle showing/hiding fields
 * 
 * @package Ninja Forms Conditional Logic
 * @copyright (c) 2016 WP Ninjas
 * @since 3.0
 */
define( [], function() {
    var controller = Marionette.Object.extend( {
        initialize: function() {
            nfRadio.channel( 'condition:trigger' ).reply( 'hide_field', this.hideField, this );
            nfRadio.channel( 'condition:trigger' ).reply( 'show_field', this.showField, this );
        },

        hideField: function( conditionModel, then ) {
            var targetFieldModel = nfRadio.channel( 'form-' + conditionModel.collection.formModel.get( 'id' ) ).request( 'get:fieldByKey', then.key );

            if( 'undefined' == typeof targetFieldModel ) return;
            targetFieldModel.set( 'visible', false );
            if ( ! targetFieldModel.get( 'clean' ) ) {
                targetFieldModel.trigger( 'change:value', targetFieldModel );
            }
            
            nfRadio.channel( 'fields' ).request( 'remove:error', targetFieldModel.get( 'id' ), 'required-error' );
        },

        showField: function( conditionModel, then ) {
            var targetFieldModel = nfRadio.channel( 'form-' + conditionModel.collection.formModel.get( 'id' ) ).request( 'get:fieldByKey', then.key );
            //TODO: Add an error to let the user know the show/hide field is empty.
            if( 'undefined' == typeof targetFieldModel ) return;
            targetFieldModel.set( 'visible', true );
            if ( ! targetFieldModel.get( 'clean' ) ) {
                targetFieldModel.trigger( 'change:value', targetFieldModel );
            }
            var viewEl = { el: nfRadio.channel( 'form-' + conditionModel.collection.formModel.get( 'id' ) ).request( 'get:el' ) };
            nfRadio.channel( 'form' ).request( 'init:help', viewEl );
        }
    });

    return controller;
} );
```

This is part when i compare and chose greater then 100 number and then i show or hide text input in my form:
[Github ninja form](https://github.com/wpninjas/ninja-forms-conditional-logic/blob/develop/assets/js/front-end/models/whenModel.js)

Comment: Could you provide a more expanded example, including the catch for this specific number.

Comment: I assume you missed type on the input?

Comment: @epascarello i missed it happens :).

Comment: Not sure exactly what your issue is. When I use the slider the textbox updates when I let go of the drag which is what the change event listens for. If you want it to update as you are dragging the range, you would need to use input event.

Comment: Can you post the code for "Action when the input number is set to a specific number"?

Comment: @xTrimy I have edit question.

Comment: @JaKoZo what happens when you replace `onchange` with `oninput` like epascarello mentioned?

Comment: @imvain2 the same. Oninput doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show/hide fields or even html blocks you can do that with conditional logic plugin from ninja forms. In my opinion is much more efficient setting rules/conditions in the plugin UI instead of getting stuck with custom code.

Comment: But i am using this plugin. Code fragments are from conditional logic plugin. I have problem because there is no input type range in ninja form, so i need to do it by myslef.

Comment: So you have a custom slider and a custom code that passes the value to the input field. And based on that input field you do some conditional logic in the plugin?

Comment: Yes. I need to trigger action with range slider, but it doesnt work like manually changing values in number field.